# Cannot get ngx-infinite-scroll to listen to window scroll

Tags: dom, angular8, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement [ngx-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll)
I am unable to get it to do what I want which is listen to my browser or window scroll so I may scroll content and load when needed.

What's happening is can implement this library ONLY when I set the scroll to listen to some other div so the result is two scroll bars (1) browser window scroll bar (2) content div scroll bar - this is not desirable and creates a real messy UX.
You will notice a setting in the template "scrollWindow" I have tried changing this value without any success I'm not too sure what i'm doing wrong here...

Environment

- Angular 8 with Angular Material

Template and Styling:

```
    .container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70vw;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
    <app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
<app-userpost></app-userpost>
<div *ngIf="loading">
    <app-progress-spinner></app-progress-spinner>
</div>

<!-- infinite scroll div -->
<div
class="container"
infiniteScroll
[infiniteScrollContainer]="container"
[scrollWindow]="false"
[infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
[infiniteScrollThrottle]="5"
[infiniteScrollThrottle]="300"
(scrolled)="onScrollDown()"
>

        <mat-card *ngFor="let post of postObjects">
            <mat-card-header>
                <img mat-card-avatar src={{post.profile_picture}} alt="no profile image">
                <mat-card-title>{{post.email}}</mat-card-title>
                <mat-card-subtitle> {{post.upload_date | date:"medium"}} </mat-card-subtitle>
            </mat-card-header>
            <img mat-card-image src={{post.photo}}>
            <mat-card-content>
                <p>
                    {{post.author_comment}}
                </p>
            </mat-card-content>
            <!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
            <mat-card-actions class="action-buttons">
                <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="post_like(post.post_id)">
                    <mat-icon>thumb_up_alt</mat-icon> {{post?.post_likes?.length}} Likes
                </button>
                <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="post_dislike(post.post_id)">
                    <mat-icon>thumb_down</mat-icon> {{post?.post_dislikes?.length}} Dislikes
                </button>
                <button mat-button color="primary">
                    <mat-icon>share</mat-icon> Share
                </button>
                <a mat-button color="primary" target="_blank">
                    <mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon> View
                </a>
            </mat-card-actions>

            <mat-accordion>
                <div *ngIf="post?.post_comments?.length > 0">
                    <mat-expansion-panel>
                        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                            <div class="comment-header">
                                <span class="label label-primary">{{post?.post_comments?.length}} Comments</span>
                            </div>
                        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-list>
                            <div *ngIf="post?.post_comments?.length > 0">
                                <div *ngFor="let postSection of post.post_comments; let i = index">
                                    <mat-accordion>
                                        <mat-expansion-panel>
                                            <mat-expansion-panel-header collapsedHeight="80px" expandedHeight="30px">
                                                <mat-panel-title>
                                                    <div style="max-height: 53px; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                                                        <img mat-card-avatar
                                                            src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200"
                                                            style="padding: 5px">
                                                        <strong
                                                            style="padding: 5px">{{postSection?.comment_author}}</strong>
                                                        <small style="padding: 5px">
                                                            {{postSection?.date | date:"medium"}}</small>
                                                    </div>
                                                </mat-panel-title>
                                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                            <hr>
                                            <p>{{postSection?.post_comment}}</p>
                                        </mat-expansion-panel>
                                    </mat-accordion>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </mat-list>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                </div>
            </mat-accordion>
            <form [formGroup]="PostComment">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div id="container">
                        <div id="profile_img">
                            <div class="actions">
                                <div class="avatar">
                                    <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src={{userAvatar}} alt="Cannot Load Photo"
                                        width="30" height="30">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <textarea matInput formControlName="post_comment" #message maxlength="500"
                                placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
                            <mat-hint align="start">
                                <strong>Say something constructive..</strong>
                            </mat-hint>
                            <mat-hint align="end">{{message.value.length}} / 500</mat-hint>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <div class="post-button">
                            <button mat-raised-button (click)="createComment(post.post_id)">Post</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </mat-card>
        <div *ngIf="end_of_data">
                <strong><h3>No More Data To Load..</h3></strong>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: I was not, I set it off to the side for now @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer .. I will be coming back to it shortly

Comment: have you tried changing the directive `infiniteScrollContainer` by wrapping the css class .container in quotes and add the dot in the class so it becomes `[infiniteScrollContainer]="'.container'"`

Answer (score 0):

change this [infiniteScrollContainer]="container" by [infiniteScrollContainer]="'.container'"

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed similar problem by adding `[fromRoot]="true"` and removing `[scrollWindow]="false"`. This will give the following `<div>`

```
<div
    infiniteScroll
    [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
    [infiniteScrollThrottle]="5"
    [infiniteScrollThrottle]="300"
    (scrolled)="onScrollDown()"
    [fromRoot]="true"
>
```